# how to use append data in an array in php 7

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling, php-7

I left php but there is a problem in my code. and review there is lot of difference b/w php 5 n 7 so have a look this

php 5

```
while ($result = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
   $res[]=$result;
}
return $res;
```

so this cause error in php 7

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my/xxx/xxx/db.php:73 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my/xxx/xxx/index.php(12): Database->show_all('admin') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/xxx/xxx/db.php on line 73
```

can you tell me how to write this in php 7

Comment: Can you add what error your getting in PHP 7 to your question.

Comment: I edit my question please check

Comment: How should that have worked in php5 if `$res` is a string? And what is it meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be defining `$res` as

```
$res = '';
```

which is defining it as a string.

You need to make sure it's initialised as an array to use the `[]` approach...

```
$res = [];
while ($result = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
   $res[]=$result;
}
return $res;
```

Comment: I got answer before you but you deserve this ;)

Answer (score 0):

`array_push()` might be the solution you are looking for

```
while ($result = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
  array_push($res, $result);
}
return $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

$res = []; while ($result = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { $res[]=$result; } return $res;

It work